Understand the difference in finding the distributions of a hypergeometric random variable and a binomial RV
To find the probability mass function for the hypergeometric distribution, I came across the following descriptive formula:
Suppose I have a jar with $N$ marbles, $r$ red marbles and the rest are white marbles. Suppose now I randomly select $n$ marbles without replacement. One way to formulate the probability mass function for finding $k$ red marbles is to find the number of combinations that yield $k$ red marbles and $n-k$ white marbles and normalize that with the number of ways of choosing n marbles from $N$.
This would result in $P[X=k]=\frac{\binom{r}{k}\binom{N-r}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$
The segment of such an explanation that I do not understand is where the assumption is made that the marbles are selected without replacement. As such how would this description change when we do assume replacement, namely when we consider a binomial distribution instead?
I was wondering if anyone could clarify my query?

Witout replacement, the probabilities go on changing with each selection, whereas with replacement, they remain constant. If we select two consecutive aces without replacement, $Pr = \frac4{52}\frac3{51}$, whereas with replacement it will be $\frac4{52}\frac4{52}$. That is the difference between the hyergeometric distribution and the binomial distribution
